# Is there a more efficient way i can deal with a 10+ minute system delay that i need to check the response of

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

I am Automating some integration tests that will span across two systems.

(These tests will be hosted in a GOCD Pipeline to run automatically.)

*System A*

*System B*

An issue is logged in system B which provides a reference number specific to System B and sends a request to System A for a reference specific to System A.

I need to check the System A reference number that is returned. However, this reference may not arrive for 10+ minutes.

How should I look at dealing with this?

My initial thought was to have the system wait, refresh the page. However, given there eventually will be 1000+ tests this will hog resources.

Thought number two was to store the references from System B and then have another GOCD Pipeline set up to start 15 mins or so later to go back and check for the System A Reference number.

Answer (score 0):

initiate the test during the start, write to a file , check the file whenever (may be , as ur last test), compare with time and delete the file